# Diagram application supporting SVG with connectors

Tags: graphs, charts, diagram, svg

I have a few SVGs which I want to create a diagram with. I'm looking for a software that  supports importing SVG and as well as having the ability to bind them. I mean, something like a connector as in Visio, Lucidchart which stays connected while I move the SVGs around. Is there any? On any OS.

Comment: Which operating system(s)?